# ios like date/time picker for android platform

Tags: android, datepicker, datetimepicker, uicontrol

I'm building mobile app for both ios and android platform using native ios/android code. And I want apps looks similar. So I need ios style picker (for date and time selection) available in android. I spend half of the day but don't find any sutable variant. Will be more than happy if you suggest something. I think there should be variants, because I saw several android apps where picker looks the same as on ios (anydo for example).

What I already checked:

1. [android-spinnerwheel](https://github.com/ai212983/android-spinnerwheel) (abandoned, not sutable for using, require build actual picker from it's componet, so quite a lot of code)
2. [wheelpicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker) (quality unclear, regional standards/datetime constants hardcoded in code and in general control hard to customize, however it's candidate for forking and fixing things manually. For sure it's not supporting am-pm/24h UI switching)
3. [PickView](https://github.com/brucetoo/PickView) (no layout, implemented as dialog, poore customization abilities)
4. [CharacterPickerView](https://github.com/alafighting/CharacterPickerView) (do not use default layout settings, hard to customize without fixing sources, hardcoded values, GPL license)

P.S. I will cosinder payed variants if they exists.

---

After investigation we ended up with custom controls build based on [wheelpicker](https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker)

Comment: Hi you got any solution.. Even I am stuck same situation and searching.. can you please give me any hint or code..?? Thanks..

Comment: I created a library to solve this issue : https://arkapp.medium.com/ios-date-time-picker-for-android-93af45fdfaf0

Comment: @abdulrehman, your library is good, but  what do I do if I want only first letter in capital and other letters in small for text in Cancel button and Submit button?

Answer (score 2):

You can Use wheel type effect in android here is code:

```
<DatePicker
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:calendarViewShown="false"
   android:datePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use wheel type effect in android  here is code:

https://github.com/ayushhgoyal/AyushWheel/

Hope this will Help ! Cheers !

Comment: project abandoned since last commit was more than 2 years ago. And control itself don't looks sutable for use in production.

Comment: anyone looking for iOS like date time picker for Android - try this one https://github.com/florent37/SingleDateAndTimePicker

Comment: Check this new iOS like date time picker https://github.com/blessedCode07/iOS-date-time-picker